# How to avoid unrelated data from sql search

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

When I search postgresql with this code

```
select count ( * ) from test_eu where eng_discription ~ '.* led .* and .* car .*';
```

I want to get the results of related to "LED parts for car"
but results include those unrelated data like

so-cal**led** **car**dboard

**car**efully instal**led**

How can I avoid those unrelated data?

Comment: You can't search for 'LED parts for car' ? A string is a string unless you have rules for entering led parts for car then you will struggle, a better design would be to hold part type and what it might be applicable to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use word boundaries:

```
select count(*) cnt
from test_eu
where eng_discription ~* '\yled\y.*\yand\y.*\ycar\y';
```

### Demo

The regex used here will match any input containing the words `led`, `and`, `car`, in that order, regardless of case.  Check the demo link to see the logic working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed advice.
It helps me a lot!!